# VNCoreMLModel slow start up time

Tags: ios, coreml

Has anyone had any issues with the first call to `VNImageRequestHandler`?

I'm testing out `VNCoreMLModel` with Apples `MobileNet.mlmodel` and the first request I make through `VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: sourceImage, orientation: imageOrientation)` takes about 1.9 seconds but each subsequent request takes 0.213 seconds. I'm generating the request by simply doing: `VNCoreMLRequest(model: model, completionHandler: { ... }`. I'm not setting a `CIContext` when generating the requested handler (`VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: sourceImage, orientation: imageOrientation)`), instead, letting the system handle that, which I thought would generate some overhead but when specifying one myself in `VNImageRequestHandler` I can see the request ignores that `CIContext`.

So really my question is what could be causing the time difference between the first and second requests.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall seeing this before, although perhaps I didn't pay enough attention. But there are a few things that need to happen the first time you use a model, especially if it runs on the GPU:

- The model weights need to be loaded into memory and converted to the format used by the GPU kernels.
- The GPU kernels need to be loaded.
- The GPU needs to "get in the groove". For speed tests, you want to make a few passes through the model first so that the GPU is warmed up, and then do the measurements.
- The very first time you use an MPS kernel after installing an app, the Metal bytecode needs to be compiled to specific machine code for the GPU in your device.

If the model runs on the CPU or the Neural Engine, it's likely that similar initialization steps are necessary. It's hard to say exactly what happens because Core ML hides all of this stuff.